# how to hide the exizting double click event(appointment form) in the xtrascheduler

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii,

I am using devexpress xtrascheduler.In this i have created one custom form which opens  while double clicking .But the problem is now while double clicking two forms are opening ie,one custom form that i have created and the other default one.so i need to hide the default form and need to show the custom form that i have created.How it can be done??plz help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the [EditAppointmentFormShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_EditAppointmentFormShowingtopic) event and set the e.Handled parameter to true.